# (UWP) Linking the VKontakte SDK in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vk

I'm currently developing an app that makes use of the VK API and so far I've been rolling my own in terms of API calls, but I think that going forward, using their SDK might be favorable.

Their documentation, however only says to "add a link" to the SDK and contains a link to a github page (see https://vk.com/dev/wp_sdk)

As someone who hasn't worked with SDKs before, I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but how would I go about adding this link without a wizard like NuGet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should download a project from github page, and copy project "**VK.WindowsPhone.SDK**" to your solution, and then reference it in your solution.

Another option is: open it in visual studio, then build it yourself. Then just take the libraries generated by compiler to your application folder, then reference them using "Add Reference" - specifically that **VK.WindowsPhone.SDK.dll**

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a feeling it was something simple like this, but better safe than sorry.